# How do I get $\omega$ in de Broglie’s formula?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, fourier-transform, frequency

Suppose I have the ground state $\psi$ of some Hamiltonian $H$ and I want to get energy eigenvalue of $\psi$ without doing $H \psi = E \psi$.

De Broglie’s formula $$
E = \hbar \omega,
$$says I can get $E$ provided I know $\omega$. How do I calculate this $\omega$ in that case? I imagine the Fourier transform would give me a range of $\omega$. Is de Broglie a bridge between Fourier analysis and quantum mechanics that can be made mathematically precise?

Comment: *"De Broglie’s formula says I can get $E$ provided I know $ω$."* [citation needed] I view de Broglie's formula as the *definition* of the de Broglie wavelength for an arbitrary quantum state and I don't understand why you think you can compute $\omega$ from something other than the energy in general.

Comment: Some good information on this in this video from 3blue1brown [The more general uncertainty principle, beyond quantum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBnnXbOM5S4&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPHLHBuY0nPbAQ_WGEjtzLW&index=3&t=0s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two quantum mechanical systems which are defined on the same Hilbert space (e.g. the free particle on a line and the harmonic oscillator, which are both defined on $L^2(\mathbb R)$) are distinguished *only* by which operator is chosen to be the Hamiltonian. It follows immediately that any procedure which gives you information about the set of energy eigenstates must reflect this choice.

---

I have never seen the relation you quote referred to as the "de Broglie formula."  Nevertheless, this doesn't provide a workaround to dealing with the Hamiltonian operator; it merely relates the energy of an eigenstate to the frequency at which its phase oscillates.  Finding the allowed frequencies simply amounts to finding the allowed energies and then dividing by $\hbar$.

Explicitly, the Schrödinger equation says that if $\psi(t)$ is the state of the system at time $t$, then
$$i\hbar \psi'(t) = H \psi(t)$$
If $\psi(t)$ is an eigenstate of $H$ with eigenvalue $E$, then it follows that
$$i\hbar \psi'(t) = E\psi(t) \implies \psi'(t) = -\frac{iE}{\hbar} \psi(t)$$
$$\implies \psi(t) = \psi_0 e^{-iEt/\hbar} =\psi_0 e^{-i\omega t},\ \ \ \omega\equiv \frac{E}{\hbar}$$

This tells us that eigenstates of the Hamiltonian evolve via a periodic phase factor with frequency $\omega = E/\hbar$.